# Bundler: inherit gems from another dependency?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

I work on several Ruby and Rails projects, and find myself frustrated by the need to manage the same dependencies and configurations across all of them. I was thinking it would be great if I could publish a meta gem that includes all of my common dependencies. However, many of these are testing/development dependencies ([`rspec`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec)/[`brakeman`](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman)), so it doesn't seem like it would make sense to make them a normal dependency inside the `.gemspec`. Is there some way in the `Gemfile` to specify `:test` or `:development` dependencies of another gem? The only thing that comes to mind for me is to publish 3 different gems, and specify `runtime` dependencies in each, e.g.:

```
gem "my-meta-gem"
gem "my-meta-gem-development", group: :development
gem "my-meta-gem-test", group: :test
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with a single gem?

Comment: What about having your gem have a gem file available in the lib path? Then you could require that file in your gem file... it would be a bit odd to do, but it should work...

Comment: Hmm, I think that introduces a chicken/egg situation, where the gem has to be in your Gemfile for you to install it and then somehow reference dependencies inside of it.

Comment: It would, wouldn't it? But I think you have that issue anyway...